# Boost spirit how check value of token?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

How I can check in next code that value of last `tok.identifier` is '='-character?

```
parameter = (
                    tok.identifier
                    >> ((lit(":")
                    >> tok.identifier) |
                    (tok.identifier >> statement))
                    );
```

EDIT. I declare identifier `lex::token_def<std::string> identifier;`

Comment: in what universe does `identifier` match `=`?. Also, include the token definitions (in your SSCCE) if you want help. Are you using an `actor_lexer`? Are you using `token_def<T>`? Are you adding the `T`s to the `mpl::vector` in the lexer declaration?

Comment: I use `token_def<T>` and, I use lexer with parser `lex::tokenize_and_parse`. That code in ask is from parser/grammar.

Comment: I know it's from the rule definition. But you don't show any of the relevant types. Sorry, but that means we can't help (except making up the whole code ourselves, and (a) I have better things to do with my time (b) that would just risk answering with irrelevant code)

Answer (score 0):

The correspondent concept in `boost::spirit::qi` is described by `qi::lit`. You have to create a `qi::lit` for your tokens. Here is an example:

```
template <typename TokenAttr>
struct LiteralToken : qi::primitive_parser<LiteralToken<TokenAttr>>
{
    LiteralToken(const lex::token_def<TokenAttr> &tok, const TokenAttr &value)
      : id(tok.id())
      , value(value)
    {}

    template <typename Context, typename Iterator>
    struct attribute
    {
        typedef unused_type type;
    };

    template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename Skipper, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context& context, Skipper const& skipper, Attribute& attr_) const
    {
        typedef typename Iterator::token_type::token_value_type token_value_type;
        typedef typename Iterator::base_iterator_type base_iterator_type;

        base_iterator_type it;

        qi::skip_over(first, last, skipper);
        if (first != last && id == first->id())
        {
            auto v = boost::get<boost::iterator_range<base_iterator_type>>(first->value());
            if (v == value)
            {
                traits::assign_to(*first, attr_);
                ++first;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    typename lex::token_def<TokenAttr>::id_type id;
    TokenAttr                                   value;
};

namespace boost
{
    namespace spirit
    {
        template <typename A0, typename A1>
        struct use_terminal<
            qi::domain
          , terminal_ex<tag::lit, fusion::vector2<A0, A1>>
          , typename enable_if<boost::is_same<A0, lex::token_def<std::string>>>::type
          > : mpl::true_
        {};

        namespace qi
        {
            template <typename Modifiers, typename A0, typename A1>
            struct make_primitive<
                terminal_ex<tag::lit, fusion::vector2<A0, A1> >
              , Modifiers
              , typename enable_if<boost::is_same<A0, lex::token_def<std::string>>>::type
              >
            {
                typedef LiteralToken<std::string> result_type;

                template <typename Terminal>
                result_type operator()(Terminal const& term, unused_type) const
                {
                    return result_type(fusion::at_c<0>(term.args), fusion::at_c<1>(term.args));
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write

```
parameter = (
                    lit(tok.identifier, "=")
                    >> ((lit(":")
                    >> tok.identifier) |
                    (tok.identifier >> statement))
                    );
```

Comment: I just checked boost 1.65.1. qi::lit is defined for char, string, bool, integers and real numbers. It is not defined for lex::token_def.

Comment: I never said it's called `lit`. It's not. I think it was `id_token(id)` or `token_id(id)` or something (maybe even `any_token(id)` or just `qi::token(id)`). I'll look for it later

Comment: Ok. I checked all terminals defined in the lexer. I found these: in_state, plain_raw_token, plain_token, plain_token_range, plain_tokenid, plain_tokenid_range, plain_tokenid_mask, state_switcher, and state_switcher_context. None of them checks the literal value of a token.

Comment: Do you happen to have a self-contained sample using your code? I will try to look at this tomorrow.

Comment: I don't. I have it in my project and it is working. I cannot share the project. Just copy&paste what I posted and try to use a rule that looks like `r = qi::lit(tok.identifier, ''match-this-literally")`. In my case it was useful in parsing dot language (http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language). Check compass_pt rule. It has these n, ne, e, se..., which are not keywords. It was easier not to define dedicated entities in the lexer for them.

Comment: I'm not really in the mood to invent a lexer for the purpose. I'm not a fan of spirit::lex. I might find one of my own answers with a sample though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155088/discussion-between-sehe-and-noxmetus).